# Child as he was / a child as he was

Tags: inversion, adverbial-phrases

> **Child as he was**, Tom knew a lot about science.

Why can't " **A child as he was**" be used instead?

Comment: What is the source?? Who says "A" can't be used?

Comment: @JamesK  I wouldn't necessarily say *can't*, but the "article noun" version seems much less common, if you look at Ngrams.

Comment: "A child as he was" could have been used instead, but was not.

Comment: @stangdon The point is that any question that quotes a line of text should cite the source of that line.  And any question that asks "Why is '...' ungrammatical?" should explain why the OP believes it is ungrammatical.  THis question did neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence:

> (1) **Child as he was**, Tom knew a lot about science.

Is a rather literary, somewhat old-fashioned form. It would not commonly be used in informal speech. It means, essentially:

> (2) **Although he was a Child**, Tom knew a lot about science.

Another, possibly clearer, form would be:

> (3) **Child though he was**, Tom knew a lot about science.

The suggested alternate:

> (4) **A child as he was**, Tom knew a lot about science.

I have not encountered often, and it somehow does not seem right to me, but I cannot specify any rule that it violates. But I don't think that I would use it.

Form (1) is often used where thereis an apparent contradiction, as a in this case. Tom knows a lot about science, even thoguh Tom is a child, and children often do not know a lot about science. Form (2) makes this more explicit. However form (1) can akso be sued when the two parts confirm each other, rather seem to be contradictory. For example:

> (1A) Scholar as he was, George used language with precision.

Only the sense can tell one if form (1) or (1A) is being used.